# Jenkins master fault tolerance

Tags: jenkins

I’d like to set Jenkins in fault tolerant mode, so if one of masters is down, second master should pick up failed job and re-trigger it.

I don’t have to care about slaves because slaves are on-demand Docker containers.

Any ideas about how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas about how it (Jenkins HA) could be done?

[CloudBees](https://www.cloudbees.com/) provides a [commercial Jenkins HA solution](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-jenkins-platform/enterprise-edition/features/high-availability-plugin).

Comment: Any free alternatives?

Comment: @kagarlickij Maybe JenkinsX or another approach to Jenkins on Kubernetes